# Парсинг document.cookie с помощью PHP

Tags: php

Имею допустим такую строку:

```
"remixab=1; remixseenads=0"
```

Как мне ее превратить в json вида:

```
{
"remixtab" : 1,
"remixseenads" : 0
}
```

?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-parse-cookie.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714638/how-can-i-parse-serverhttp-cookie-in-pure-php

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "remixab=1; remixseenads=0";

foreach (explode('; ', $str) as $k => $v) {
    preg_match('/^(.*?)=(.*?)$/i', trim($v), $matches);
    $cookie[trim($matches[1])] = urldecode($matches[2]);
}

echo json_encode($cookie);
```